# Как назначить асинхронный клиент для всего класса?

Tags: python, асинхронность, asyncio

как я могу определить асинхронный клиент только один раз - одно подключение к серверу, а затем работать с ним, но я не могу понять, как определить этот клиент глобальным для класса. Я просто догадался создавать новое соединение перед каждым использованием, но, конечно, это лишняя трата времени. Буде рад любым предложениям. Библиотека: https://pypi.org/project/python-binance/

Рабочий код:

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient

class Binance:
    async def get_trades(self):
        client = await AsyncClient.create() # define two times(two connections) need only one
        aggregate_trades = await client.get_all_tickers()
        print(aggregate_trades)
        await client.close_connection()

    async def exchange_info(self):
        client = await AsyncClient.create() # define two times(two connections) need only one
        exchange_info = await client.get_exchange_info()
        print(exchange_info)
        await client.close_connection()

async def main():
    b = Binance()
    await asyncio.gather(b.get_trades(), b.exchange_info())
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Должно быть (но не работает):

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient

class Binance:
    def __init__(self):
        asyncio.run(self.async_init())

    async def async_init(self):
        self.client = await AsyncClient.create() # define only one time because use much time

    async def get_trades(self):
        aggregate_trades = await self.client.get_all_tickers()
        print(aggregate_trades)

    async def exchange_info(self):
        exchange_info = await self.client.get_exchange_info()
        print(exchange_info)

async def main():
    b = Binance()
    await asyncio.gather(b.get_trades(), b.exchange_info())
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Ну так создайте его в функции main и передайте классу Binance.

Comment: ну я все понимаю но мне каждый раз при вызове класса снова клиент создавать и подключать который по логике должен сам подключаться и при инициализации в __init__, но мне б просто чтоб само а не я юдобавляю что то отдельно(обязательное) чтоб клас воркал

Comment: в маин создайте клиент, передайте Binance, работайте. В конце main закройте клиент. Если поддерживает async with то еще проще

Comment: ну твой метод ворк ето да, а async with не ворк к сожелению. Сенкс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient

class Binance:
    async def async_init(self):
        self.client = await AsyncClient.create() # define only one time because use much time

    async def get_trades(self):
        aggregate_trades = await self.client.get_all_tickers()
        print(aggregate_trades)

    async def exchange_info(self):
        exchange_info = await self.client.get_exchange_info()
        print(exchange_info)

async def main():
    b = Binance()
    await b.async_init()
    await asyncio.gather(b.get_trades(), b.exchange_info())
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Или

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient

class Binance:

    @classmethod
    async def create(cls):
        self = cls()
        self.client = await AsyncClient.create()

    async def get_trades(self):
        aggregate_trades = await self.client.get_all_tickers()
        print(aggregate_trades)

    async def exchange_info(self):
        exchange_info = await self.client.get_exchange_info()
        print(exchange_info)

async def main():
    b = await Binance.create()
    await asyncio.gather(b.get_trades(), b.exchange_info())
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```